# Read last column of the file and compare the data using c

Tags: c, file

**Hello everyone,**
     I have to modify the data in the file using c program.

**Flow process**
1.  Read the file and find the section using string compare function.
2.  In that section, read the last column of the data.
3.  Compare the data with input, if both are same change that specific value.

```
 For example 
 - if User input = "2" and the last column value of the line also "2"
 - then change that value to "4" as it is shown in example input and output file
```

4. In example input, row 4-6 last column value is "2" after the process the example output value is changed from 2 to "4"

**For example**
**Input**

```
Coordinates
Elements      
1  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  1  
2  4 3 9 10 8 7 11 12  1  
3  10 9 13 14 12 11 15 16  1  
4  14 13 17 18 16 15 19 20  2  
5  18 17 21 22 20 19 23 24  2  
6  22 21 25 26 24 23 27 28  2  
7  26 25 29 30 28 27 31 32  1  
8  30 29 33 34 32 31 35 36  1  
9  34 33 37 38 36 35 39 40  1  
End_elements
End_Coordinates
```

**output**

```
Coordinates
Elements      
1  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  1  
2  4 3 9 10 8 7 11 12  1  
3  10 9 13 14 12 11 15 16  1  
4  14 13 17 18 16 15 19 20  4  
5  18 17 21 22 20 19 23 24  4  
6  22 21 25 26 24 23 27 28  4  
7  26 25 29 30 28 27 31 32  1  
8  30 29 33 34 32 31 35 36  1  
9  34 33 37 38 36 35 39 40  1  
End_elements
End_Coordinates
```

I have tried to write program to do this process but, i don't know how to read last column and do the comparison process.

i have tried to write program to perform change in value but i failed. please suggest me the process to finish this operation

my code is given here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define END_ELEMENTS  "END_ELEMENTS "
#define ELEMENTS "ELEMENTS "

FILE *file1;
FILE *out1;

void OpenInputFile();
int Extract_Node_value( char *To_Find_node, char *To_Element_set_list);


int main()
{
  double result;

  OpenInputFile();

  out1 = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    if (out1 == NULL)
     {
       perror("fopen");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

      result = Extract_Node_value(ELEMENTS, END_ELEMENTS);
      printf("%s", result);
      fclose(file1);
      fclose(out1);

    return 0;
}// end main

int Extract_Node_value( char *To_Find_node, char *To_Element_set_list)
{
   char line[256];
   char line1[256];

   int Compare_value = 2;
   int Change_value  = 4;

   int word;
   int fword;

      if (!file1) {
      perror("fopen");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),file1)) {
           // fprintf(out1, " %s ", line);
           if (!strstr(line, To_Find_node)){
            continue;
           }

           while(fgets(line, sizeof line,file1)) {
           printf("%s \n", line);
           fprintf(out1, "%s", line);

              while (sscanf(line, "%d%*[^\n]", &fword)){

      /// i have tried to write program to perform change in value but i failed
    please suggest me the process to finish this operation

                  fgets(line, sizeof line,file1);
                    if (strstr(line, To_Element_set_list)){
                        return 0;
                    }
                      fprintf(out1, "%s", line);

          }
      }
   }
       return 0;
}

 void OpenInputFile(){

   file1 = fopen("input.txt", "r");

 /// check if file exists
  if (!file1){

   perror("fopen");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

 return ;

}
```

Comment: This is a homework assignment, so I won't give you any code. What's with all those nested loops reading lines from the file?  The basic algorithm should be read a line, search for the value, if found, change it, then write that line to out1.

Comment: So, once you have the line in a buffer, scan it from end to start in a loop:
`for (char *col = line + strlen(line) - 1; s != line; col--) {}`, when you find the first white space, *col will be pointing one character in front of the first numeric in the last column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as you mentioned in that loop once i find the space, i will compare the value and change it?

Comment: Unless you absolutely need to use string comparison functions, you can simply use `if (*line < '0' || '9' < *line) continue;` to check whether the 1st character is not `0-9` to skip to the data section.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the compiler warning level to maximum (see comments below). This should show many warnings and help you fix the code.

`strstr(line, To_Find_node)` will do a case sensitive comparison. You can use `strnicmp` in this case.

I am not sure why you are using `sscanf` when it appears you are reading from the file! Just use `fscanf(file1, "%d", &fword)` to read the integers and break when it fails. Example:

```
#define END_ELEMENTS  "END_ELEMENTS "
#define ELEMENTS "ELEMENTS "

FILE *file1;
FILE *out1;

void Extract_Node_value(char *To_Find_node, char *To_Element_set_list)
{
    char line[256];

    int fword;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file1))
    {
        fprintf(out1, "%s", line);
        if(strnicmp(line, To_Find_node, strlen(To_Find_node)) == 0)
            break;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        int i = 0;

        //read 9 columns:
        for(; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if(fscanf(file1, "%d", &fword) != 1)
                break;
            fprintf(out1, "%d ", fword);
        }

        //we couldn't read any
        if(i != 9)
            break;

        //read the last column:
        if(fscanf(file1, "%d", &fword) != 1)
            break;

        //change it here:
        fprintf(out1, "(%d)", fword * 100);

        fprintf(out1, "\n");
    }

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file1)) 
        fprintf(out1, "%s", line);
}

int main()
{
    file1 = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (!file1) return 0;

    out1 = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    if (!out1) return 0;

    Extract_Node_value(ELEMENTS, END_ELEMENTS);

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(out1);

    return 0;
}
```

You should also consider not declaring `file1` and `out1` as global variables, it's not necessary. Declare them in `main` instead, and pass them to the function. Don't create extra functions for opening and closing the files.

Comment: I'm not sure what `Level 4` is, but you may want to insure that if using `gcc`, they include at least `-Wall -Wextra`, if using `clang` include `-Weverything` and if using VS (`cl.exe`) they use `/Wall` or `/W4` (I guess that is what you were referring to)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the clarification, I edited that part. I meant /Wall or /W4 for VS.

Comment: Yep, I saw it, good advise on enabling warnings, but I only get 1-vote and that already been given `:)`

Comment: See edited section. I had an error earlier, I should have used `strnicmp` because `fgets` reads blank space and `\n` at the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks for your help! i have one doubt, if we use larger files and we dont know the number of column we have to change?

Comment: sometimes, between coordinates to Elements there is values. That is reason i used strstr function to find Elements and End_elements .

Answer (score 1):

You make things a bit unwieldly by sectioning your read using multiple `fgets` and `fscanf` blocks. Ideally, you simply want to read through your input file, one-line-at-a-time and take appropriate actions based on the content of the line. Whether you simply write it out to the outputfile unchanged, or whether it contains the data you must parse the final value in the last column, compare with your input value and change to the new value before writing it to the output file.

Wile you can *tokenize* the lines with numbers, you can `scanf` down the buffer, or you can simply use `strchr (buf, '\n');` to return a pointer to the `'\n'` at the end of each line with numbers and then back-up until you are in front of the last number. (if the `strchr` call fails to return a pointer `'\n'`, then you know that was a partial read with `fgets` and you will read the remainder of the line on the next call. (note: it also requires your file to have a POSIX line ending on the last line)

The whole task can be simplified where you are only swapping single digits, you can simply use the character values for comparison and substitution in the buffer becomes trivial. To preserve capability, the conversion to `int` is retained, and noted where additional checks would be need for multi-digit values.

Putting this approach together, you could do something like the following. It reads each line, then parses the contents of the buffer with a pair of pointers, a couple character classification functions from `ctype.h` and `strchr` to obtain a pointer to the end of the buffer.

The program expects the `infile` and `outfile` as the first two arguments for the command line. [it will take an optional two (1) the value to compare and (2) the replacement value] as well,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXC 512

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int val = 0,
        rep = 0;
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    FILE *ifp = NULL,
         *ofp = NULL;

    if (argc < 3 ) {    /* validate at least 2 arguments given */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input\n"
                        "usage: %s infile outfile [find replace]\n",
                        argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    ifp = fopen (argv[1], "r"); /* open infile for reading */
    ofp = fopen (argv[2], "w"); /* open ofile for writing */

    if (!ifp || !ofp) { /* validate files open for reading/writing */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    errno = 0;  /* reset errno - convert find/replace values */
    val = argc > 3 ? (int)strtol (argv[3], NULL, 10) : 2;
    rep = argc > 4 ? (int)strtol (argv[4], NULL, 10) : 4;
    if (errno) {    /* validate no errors */
        perror ("strtol failure");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, ifp)) {    /* read each line */
        char *p = buf,  /* pair of pointers to buf */
            *ep = buf;
        int tmp = 0;    /* temp value to hold number read at last col */
        while (*p && isspace (*p))  /* discard leading whitespace */
            p++;
        /* is current a digit or ending '\n' not present */
        if (!isdigit (*p) || !(ep = strchr (p, '\n'))) {
            fprintf (ofp, "%s", buf);   /* write buf to ofile */
            continue;
        }
        p = ep - 1;     /* set p to point to last char before '\n' */
        while (p > buf && isspace (*p)) /* remove trailing whitespace */
            p--;
        ep = p;         /* update ep to point to ending number in file */
        while (p > buf && isdigit (*p)) /* backup to start of number */
            p--;
        p++;            /* +1 to point to the first digit in number */
        // if (p != ep) { /* handle multi-digit number */ }
        ep = p;     /* reset ep to p */
        errno = 0;  /* reset errno */
        tmp = (int)strtol (ep, NULL, 10);   /* convert last col number */
        if (errno) {    /* validate conversion and handle error */
            perror ("strlol failure");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (val == tmp) /* if equal to search val, replace val with rep */
            *p = (char)(rep + '0'); /* you must convert rep to ASCII digit */
        fprintf (ofp, "%s", buf);   /* output modified bug to new file */
    }

    fclose (ifp);       /* close input file */
    if (fclose (ofp)) { /* validate output file close after write */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: stream error after write.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/lastcol.txt
Coordinates
Elements
1  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  1
2  4 3 9 10 8 7 11 12  1
3  10 9 13 14 12 11 15 16  1
4  14 13 17 18 16 15 19 20  2
5  18 17 21 22 20 19 23 24  2
6  22 21 25 26 24 23 27 28  2
7  26 25 29 30 28 27 31 32  1
8  30 29 33 34 32 31 35 36  1
9  34 33 37 38 36 35 39 40  1
End_elements
End_Coordinates
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/chglastcol dat/lastcol.txt dat/lastcolout.txt
```

**Output File**

```
$ cat dat/lastcolout.txt
Coordinates
Elements
1  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  1
2  4 3 9 10 8 7 11 12  1
3  10 9 13 14 12 11 15 16  1
4  14 13 17 18 16 15 19 20  4
5  18 17 21 22 20 19 23 24  4
6  22 21 25 26 24 23 27 28  4
7  26 25 29 30 28 27 31 32  1
8  30 29 33 34 32 31 35 36  1
9  34 33 37 38 36 35 39 40  1
End_elements
End_Coordinates
```

---

**Requirement to use `strtok` (from comment)**

If you have a requirement to use `strtok`, then you must first **make a copy** of the line you read because `strtok` will modify the string it processes. This matters when you go to write your modified string back out. Since you are focused on the last column only, you will essentially just run your string through `strtok`, ignoring the results, but *saving a pointer* to the last token.

When `strtok` exits, you then have a pointer to the last value you can test against your replacement. It being the last, you can simply verify you have enough room in your buffer, overwrite the value to replace with your new value (as a string), *nul-terminate* and then append a `'\n'`.

By simply replacing the last value in your string, your preserve the original spacing in your file. If you simply decided to build a new line from the tokens, you would have no idea whether you had 1-space between the values or 100-spaces between them.

I have limited the example to the last column according to your question, but to replace any column value, you essentially just add a check, e.g. `if (colindex == col)` inside the `strtok` loop and do the same value-check and write the new value to the buffer, but instead of just appending a `'\n'`, you need to append the remainder of the line you are tokenizing and keep going (that is left for the future)

Putting the `strtok` bits together, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXN  16
#define MAXC 512

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int val = 0,
        rep = 0;
    char buf[MAXC] = "",
        *delim = " \n"; /* strtok delimiters */
    FILE *ifp = NULL,
        *ofp = NULL;

    if (argc < 3 ) {    /* validate at least 2 arguments given */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input\n"
                        "usage: %s infile outfile [find replace]\n",
                        argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    ifp = fopen (argv[1], "r"); /* open infile for reading */
    ofp = fopen (argv[2], "w"); /* open ofile for writing */

    if (!ifp || !ofp) { /* validate files open for reading/writing */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    errno = 0;  /* reset errno - convert find/replace/col values */
    val = argc > 3 ? (int)strtol (argv[3], NULL, 10) : 2;
    rep = argc > 4 ? (int)strtol (argv[4], NULL, 10) : 4;
    if (errno) {    /* validate no errors */
        perror ("strtol failure 1");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, ifp)) {    /* read each line */
        char cpy[MAXC] = "",    /* copy of buf for strtok */
            *p = cpy,           /* pair of pointers to cpy */
            *ep = cpy,
            numstr[MAXN] = "",  /* buffer to hold rep as string */
            *np = numstr;       /* pointer to numstr for copy */
        int tmp = 0;    /* temp value to hold number read at last col */
        size_t off = 0;     /* offset in cpy of last number */
        strcpy (cpy, buf);  /* copy before strtok -- it modifies buffer */
        for (p = strtok (p, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim)) {
            if (isdigit(*p) == 0)   /* does token begin with digit */
                goto labelline;     /* bail - just print the line */
            ep = p;                 /* save last token address */
        }
        p = ep;     /* reset p to ep (last token) */
        errno = 0;  /* reset errno */
        tmp = (int)strtol (p, &ep, 10);   /* convert col to number */
        if (p == ep || errno) { /* validate conversion and handle error */
            perror ("strlol failure 3");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (val == tmp) {                       /* do we replace? */
            off = p - cpy;           /* get offset to number in buf */
            sprintf (numstr, "%d", rep);        /* get rep as string */
            for (; *np && off + 3 < MAXC; np++) /* copy at off in buf */
                buf[off++] = *np;
            buf[off] = 0;                       /* nul-terminate */
            strcat (buf, "\n");                 /* add a newline */
        }
        labelline:;
        fprintf (ofp, "%s", buf);           /* output buf to new file */
    }

    fclose (ifp);       /* close input file */
    if (fclose (ofp)) { /* validate output file close after write */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: stream error after write.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** the check of `*np && off + 3` insures space for the last character, the `'\n'` and the *nul-terminating* character.

**also note:** you can to the testing with `strcmp` without ever having converted the values read from the file to `int`. Each method has advantages/disadvantages, just be aware you can approach it that way as well.

The output is the same as above.

**Change Any Specified Column Where Number Matches Value**

The problem can be looked at another way to do all comparisons and replacements using the string representation of the `val` and `rep` (replacement) completely avoiding the conversion to and from integer values. This can be done simply by changing characters in the original `buf` ***only if `val` and `rep` are the same length***. Otherwise, it can still be done, but a 3rd `output` buffer of `MAXC` characters would be required.

The limited case of `strlen(val) == strlen(rep)` can be generalized for any length replacement, but you would have to build the `output` buffer piece by piece as you worked down `cpy` with `strtok`, appending unchanged parts of `buf` to `output` and writing the new `rep` where `val` is found. That is left to you if you are interested.

To change the value in any column you specify with a replacement of equal length, you can do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXC 512

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int col = 0;            /* column to change (-1 = last) */
    char buf[MAXC] = "",    /* buf to read/modify */
        *val = NULL,        /* string value to change */
        *rep = NULL,        /* string value of replacement */
        *delim = " \n";     /* strtok delimiters */
    FILE *ifp = NULL,       /* input file/output file */
        *ofp = NULL;

    if (argc < 3 ) {        /* validate at least 2 arguments given */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input\n"
                        "usage: %s infile outfile [find replace]\n",
                        argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    ifp = fopen (argv[1], "r"); /* open infile for reading */
    ofp = fopen (argv[2], "w"); /* open ofile for writing */

    if (!ifp || !ofp) { /* validate files open for reading/writing */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    errno = 0;  /* reset errno - convert find/replace/col values */
    val = argc > 3 ? argv[3] : "2"; /* value to find */
    rep = argc > 4 ? argv[4] : "4"; /* replacement value */
    col = argc > 4 ? (int)strtol (argv[5], NULL, 10) : -1;
    if (errno) {    /* validate no errors */
        perror ("strtol failure 1");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (strlen (val) != strlen(rep)) {  /* check for limited case */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: length of 'val' & 'rep' differ.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, ifp)) {    /* read each line */
        char cpy[MAXC] = "",    /* copy of buf for strtok */
            *p = cpy,           /* pair of pointers to buf */
            *ep = cpy;
        int cidx = 0;           /* column index */
        strcpy (cpy, buf);      /* copy strtok modifies buffer */
        for (p = strtok (p, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim)) {
            if (isdigit(*p) == 0)   /* if 1st char non-digit */
                goto labelline;     /* just print line */
            if (cidx == col) {      /* change this col? */
                if (strcmp (p, val) == 0) { /* match value? */
                    char *rp = rep;         /* pointer to rep */
                    size_t off = p - cpy;   /* get offset in but */
                    for (; *rp && off + 3 < MAXC; rp++)
                        buf[off++] = *rp;   /* overwrite chars in buf */
                }
            }
            ep = p;     /* save pointer value for use after loop exit */
            cidx++;     /* incerment column index */
        }
        if (col == -1) {    /* change last column? */
            p = ep;
            if (strcmp (p, val) == 0) { /* do the same thing for last */
                char *rp = rep;
                size_t off = p - cpy;
                for (; *rp && off + 3 < MAXC; rp++)
                    buf[off++] = *rp;
            }
        }
        labelline:;
        fprintf (ofp, "%s", buf);   /* output modified bug to new file */
    }

    fclose (ifp);       /* close input file */
    if (fclose (ofp)) { /* validate output file close after write */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: stream error after write.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Last column change (same default case `2` -> `4`):

```
$ /bin/chgcol_strtok dat/lastcol.txt dat/lastchgcol.txt
$ cat dat/lastchgcol.txt
Coordinates
Elements
1  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  1
2  4 3 9 10 8 7 11 12  1
3  10 9 13 14 12 11 15 16  1
4  14 13 17 18 16 15 19 20  4
5  18 17 21 22 20 19 23 24  4
6  22 21 25 26 24 23 27 28  4
7  26 25 29 30 28 27 31 32  1
8  30 29 33 34 32 31 35 36  1
9  34 33 37 38 36 35 39 40  1
End_elements
```

Change column 7, replace 23 with 99:

```
$ ./bin/chgcol_strtok dat/lastcol.txt dat/lastchgcol99.txt 23 99 7
$ cat dat/lastchgcol99.txt
Coordinates
Elements
1  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  1
2  4 3 9 10 8 7 11 12  1
3  10 9 13 14 12 11 15 16  1
4  14 13 17 18 16 15 19 20  2
5  18 17 21 22 20 19 99 24  2
6  22 21 25 26 24 23 27 28  2
7  26 25 29 30 28 27 31 32  1
8  30 29 33 34 32 31 35 36  1
9  34 33 37 38 36 35 39 40  1
End_elements
End_Coordinates
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions about how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! i will come back to you once i have any questions.

Comment: Glad to help. The whole key to parsing anything from a buffer is simply to keep clear in your mind which character you are on. Then it's just a matter of "Do I need to go forward?" or "Do I need to go backwards?" to get to the next spot in the buffer you need to be at. This is the nuts-and-bolts of line parsing, so it's well worth understanding, and feel comfortable moving around in a line.

Comment: Thank you its works well. David C. what if i want to to convert two or more column in same file.

Comment: There are a number of approaches. Where I do `p = ep - 1;` I just set a pointer to the end of string and backup to get the last number. If I were doing it for any arbitrary column, I would *tokenize* all columns (e.g. with `strtok`) and then replace the value for whatever the column of interest was (or any number of replacements I needed to make). There are many, many `strtok` examples on SO. Basically instead of jumping to the end, you just keep a counter in a loop with `strtok` and if your counter matches the column to change, change it and write it out, otherwise just write it out.

Comment: Give it a try and let me know if you get stuck. (the code will probably be shorter than doing it manually as I did it above...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  as you mentioned if i use "strtok" it will read all last column of the file. then how can i replace the last column using user input

Comment: I have tried to use "strtok" and saved that last column in variable. but while compare the variable and print that changed variable in file is showing error. or values are different in file

Comment: OK, give me a bit and I'll drop an additional example using `strtok`.

Comment: Thanks for provide me proper direction to write program. In your last instruction you instructed me to use " if (colindex == col)" in strtok loop. i have tried to change two or more column at a same time by giving another input same as like before.  but while comparing that value and printing that value file makes no change. what should i do to clear this now?

Comment: Well, now you are stepping into another area where you need to form the string you will output very carefully. Here you will need to keep a flag (last col change, e.g. `lastcolchg` makes sense) Initialize to `-1`. (you use it to determine if you have made a change yet). When `(colindex == col)` if `lastcolchg < 0` then copy from `buf` to `p` to a new output buffer. Then `strcat` the new value (saving a pointer in `buf` to one past the length of the old number string -- say `pend`). You will `strcat` from `pend` to `p` before `strcat` of your next change to copy unchanged parts. Report back.

Comment: its really hard to me to understand, because i am new to program. can you provide me example to clear this.

Comment: Sorry, took me a bit, I was reworking it without the conversions to `int` to simplify the process. Give me 5 min and I'll have an update.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin at last code example, I am not sure the purpose of `ep = p;     /* save pointer value for use after loop exit */`

Comment: @jian in the `strtok()` `for` loop it will spit each column. Assigning `endpointer = pointer;` is an easy way to make sure I have a pointer to the last token (column). In the question, there is an option to modify the last column or the one specified as `argv[5]` (defaults to `-1` if no argument is given meaning change last column) So by having a pointer to the last token and checking `if (col == -1)`, I can change the last column -- if no other column number is given.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin got it make so much sense! don't even need another loop.

Comment: Yep! Assignments are cheap (much cheaper than another loop), so if you need to make an assignment each iteration and you really only care about the last one -- that's fine `:)`